# How to move image from left to right in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I move an image from left to right with jQuery?

Comment: Please remove the code block, since you haven't posted any code at all. Also, I would advise against blatantly asking for someone to "please give me a whole code." It makes it sound like you're not willing to do any of the work.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Do you want a slide animation?

Comment: The code block was actually a paragraph with the first line indented by more than 4 spaces. I've only noticed this phenomenon, recently. Has there been a change to MarkDown?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907279/jquery-animate-moving-dom-element-to-new-parent

Comment: @pavium: it has always been like that.

Comment: I meant the tendency of OPs to paste a paragraph of text into the Question, with the first line indented by, say, 8 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery for absolute beginners](http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/) is a video tutorial which explains techniques you might find useful (including animating images).

Answer (score 2):

you can use animate:

```
var _img = $("SELECTOR FOR IMAGE");
$(_img).animate(
     { "left": ($(_img).position().left  + 500 }, 
     200, //DURATION
     "linear", //EASING
     null);//CALLBACK

//Change 500 to what ever value you want the image to move by
```