# Re-ordering div positions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to mimic the vote-up vote-down system that is on this website. Is there an easy way to move the position of a div in jquery (with animations)?

Say I have the following items:

```
<div id="items">
  <div id="item1">item 1</div>
  <div id="item2">item 2</div>
  <div id="item3">item 3</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to call a function which would smoothly move item 3 up one position to:

```
<div id="items">
  <div id="item1">item 1</div>
  <div id="item3">item 3</div>
  <div id="item2">item 2</div>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$('.move-up').click(function(e){
    var $div = $(this).closest('div');

    // Does the element have anywhere to move?
    if ($div.index() > 0){
        $div.fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $div.insertBefore($div.prev('div')).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});

$('.move-down').click(function(e){
    var $div = $(this).closest('div');

    // Does the element have anywhere to move?
    if ($div.index() <= ($div.siblings('div').length - 1)){
        $div.fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $div.insertAfter($div.next('div')).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsdhs/3/)

Basically:

1. Grab the element you want to move (`$div`)
2. Fade it out (give a nice UI effect with [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/))
3. Move it either before or after the previous/next item (with [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/))
4. re-fade it back in (another UI effect with [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/))

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is by changing its css styles. Modify its position http://api.jquery.com/position/ also you can try this [How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

Comment: this won't help if you're using something like `:odd` to color rows.