# Smooth transition to divs sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a smooth transition to the divs I am sorting using jquery.

The sorting works fine but it doesn't add a smooth transition. I have used animate with a speed defined but makes no difference.

Jquery code:

```
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-down', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  elem.next().after(elem).animate(1000);
});
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-up', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  elem.prev().before(elem).animate(1000);
});
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/gvyoj63a/4/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible the way you are doing it right now. You are modifying the DOM changing the order of the elements.

Comment: Is it possible to put the line elm.next().after....inside a fade out function?

Comment: Something like elem.fadeOut('slow', function(){ //move the div})...not sure though

Comment: Sure it is possible but not transitioning/animating the CSS top value I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Got a solution using this post -- [Re-ordering div positions with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719567/re-ordering-div-positions-with-jquery)

My code --

```
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-down', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  alert(elem.index());
if (elem.index() <= (elem.siblings('div').length - 1)){
    elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
      //elem.next().after(elem).fadeIn('slow');
      elem.insertAfter(elem.next('div')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
 }

});
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-up', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  alert(elem.index());
   if (elem.index() > 0) {
    elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
      // elem.prev().before(elem).animate(1000);
      elem.insertBefore(elem.prev('div')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }
});
```

Any my demo is -- https://jsfiddle.net/gvyoj63a/5/