# Emulate drag-and-drop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that jQuery can programmatically trigger events on DOM elements that are listening to those events. For example `$el.click()` will trigger a click event on `$el` without having to physically click `$el` with the mouse.

Given two DOM elements `dom1` and `dom2`, is it possible to programmatically emulate a drag-and-drop from `dom1` to `dom2` using jQuery (or vanilla JavaScript), where `dom1` is draggable and `dom2` is droppable using jQuery UI.

Note: The reason I want to do this is to build automated UI tests.

Comment: "trigger drag-and-drop" is a little vague. I take it you want to create a drag and drop style interface, but do you mean "I want to use the [non existent] builtin drag and drop events"?

Comment: @JamWaffles: I have edited the question. I have elements which are draggable and droppable. I want to trigger dragging and dropping on those element without using the mouse, just by writing JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that jQuery.trigger does not fire the HTML event, that is, calling .click will not cause a link to be followed. It only triggers events set with jQuery.

http://jupiterjs.com/news/syn-a-standalone-synthetic-event-library is a library that truly mimics HTML events. It's very easy to use

The following asserts that 'hello' has been removed from the page:

```
Syn.click( {},'hello' )
   .type( 'Hello World' )
   .delay()         //waits 600ms seconds by default
   .drag( $('#trash') , function() {
     ok( $('#hello').length == 0, "removed hello" )
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UI then there are events `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragstop` on the draggable behavior. You should be able to invoke these programmatically by using `jQuery.trigger()` just like any other event. But, you'd need to manually manipulate the `event` instance somehow, to input the coordinates for the item to be dropped at. I'm not sure how well that would work, or why you would want to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to write UI tests.

Comment: Ahhh... now it all makes sense - you should add that this is for UI tests in your question :-) What testing framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Selenium WebDriver, but it has shortcomings for drag-and-drop.

Comment: Well it might be good to ellaborate on what issues you are having witht he draganddrop support in Selenium.

Comment: I cannot get WebDriver drag-and-drop working on a complex bit of jQuery UI. The `click_and_hold()` part works fine, but not the `move_to_element()` bit. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You want  , with animation move to a new parent. Check the function in [JQuery - animate moving DOM element to new parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907279/jquery-animate-moving-dom-element-to-new-parent)

Answer (score -1):

I normally use jquery.ui for complex things with dragging-dropping:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I have elements which are *already* draggable and droppable. I want to trigger `drag` and `drop` events without manually doing it (with the mouse).

Comment: @Randomblue Are you using jQuery UI already, or another plugin? In any case, there should be callback functions and relevant documentation. If there isn't, you could either extend/patch the plugin yourself (if it's on Github or the like), or use a different plugin.

Comment: Maybe you are actually after an animation that emulates the movement of on element into another? If so what has this to do with the user interaction?