# How to move elements in a jQuery UI .sortable() programatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, draggable

I'm looking for how to do a jQuery UI .sortable(), but without user interactions.

I have a sortable list that works by dragging the elements around, but what I really want is to move the elements programatically. Moving the element from position 5 to position 2, with all the nice animations but no user interaction.

Can this be done with .sortable()?

Comment: Maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7175811/1414562  EDIT: maybe outdated :(

Answer (score 0):

Something very close to what you try to do :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098120/jquery-ui-sortable-move-item-automatically)

The result could be :

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>test 1</li>
<li>test 2</li>
<li>test 3</li>
<li>test 4</li>
</ul>
<button>Go</button>
```

Javascript :

```
$('ul').sortable();
$('button').click(function() {
var li2 = $('li').eq(2);
var li1 = $('li').eq(1);
    var li0 = $('li').eq(0);

var oldOffset = li2.offset();
li0.after( li2 );
var newOffset = li2.offset();

var temp = li2.clone().appendTo('body')
    .css('position', 'absolute')
    .css('left', oldOffset.left)
    .css('top', oldOffset.top)
    .css('zIndex', 1000);
li2.hide();

temp.animate( {'top': newOffset.top, 'left':newOffset.left}, 'slow', function(){
   li2.show();
   temp.remove();
});

});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ro8fr37/)