# Creating a dynamic football field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to create a football field and then have some sort of dropdown menu that chooses formations (like 4-4-2, 4-5-1 etc) and moves my players (more like circles with number/name) on that field to achieve the desired formation.

Any ideas on how should I begin ?

Comment: Begin with a sketch, then try to work it out and if you stumble on any problems you could ask them here.

Comment: I'm not looking for straight answers, just need some headstart. I'm thinking about creating a div (my football pitch, with a background and whatnot) and then somehow add 11 divs on top of that (guess I'll use absolute positioning). But how would I go around moving them with Js/Jquery ? Should I change the left/top attr all the time ? Or is there a better practice.

Comment: That's a good start. Go for it and tell us when you get stuck with something. Btw. you don't need PHP for that, you could create the content in javascript as well.

Comment: I need PHP for the backend part of it (getting the players and such), going to use AJAX with Jquery for that. Anyway, thanks, guess I'm going with this.

Comment: use something like draggable and droppable from jquery UI I think those can help :D

Comment: First, let's draw it on a paper, what do you want to see on the table, what if thery are in 4-4-2, 4-5-1, etc... Then try to do it on the left side of the playground. If everything is done, thinking about a method, how can you mirror it to the right side. When all this works, then you can add popups to show player stats, etc... then you can custromize your players, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like cfv1000 said, you should look into [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) & [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) in jQuery UI.

---

Here's a head start I made for you. It's not near complete.

With your identifiers for your element(s), just call `draggable()` like this:

```
$("#GKRedTeam").draggable();
$("#GKBlueTeam").draggable();
```

..and amongst many upcoming additions - set up proper HTML & CSS properties for it.

[**JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/652/)

Comment: Say I'll use draggable/droppable. How would I store these positions generated by the drag and drop functionality for later use ? So when I edit something, I want someone else to see the same thing when he enters my page.

Comment: You need to store it with a cookie or something relevant. In order to make the animation of the droppable/draggable elements automatically you should look into animate(), offset(), css() and append(). Look into [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098120/jquery-ui-sortable-move-item-automatically). Or - you could make it easy on yourself. Just create a dropdown menu and have static images that changes upon chosen formation in the menu. Something like this I made for you [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/stsZn/23/)

Comment: No, I can't just use images, that's nothing. I think I will store the coordinates (left/top) in my database and use only predefined formations

Comment: You're thinking big already ;) Focus on the front-end first to produce a hi-fi prototype and then move to the backend is my suggestion..but good luck! :)

Comment: I liked this so much, that I am going to upvote another answer of yours! This should be accepted!!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @gsamaras

Answer (score 3):

Use http://kineticjs.com/ and you can export the image after to png or save it in the server (i think), if you want to reuse all after, you have to make objects with the same properties in PHP and save it in one database, or another option in send the objects javascript and save it without any modification (be careful with inject code), and went you have to modify the image you charge the object/information from the server.

Another option is to use localStorage if will use the same browser all the time.

See the example http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-shape-tango-with-kineticjs/ (make click in one image for the draggable)

Comment: This is too much, I am not developing a game. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The main example are game but is not only for that, for the circles with number/name is very easy, and the draggable part is one option, so you can used for anything you want, and trust me is more easy to use that jquerUI+canvas+others

Comment: Yes but I need to learn it and I don't think I'll use it in the near future for something. On the other side, jQuery UI with draggable/droppable is suitable for a number of things and althought I never looked into it, it looks like something I could use in the future aswell :).

Comment: Ok i understand, that you want to know how to do it by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

check this repository [jquery-matchcenter](https://github.com/rogerdudler/jquery-matchcenter)

A JQuery implementation of an interactive football field