# Smooth animation for cell navigation in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need create some smooth animation for cell navigation.

see what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/0ardb3u0/

When mouse located over cell, the full column and row of that cell will be selected and blue colored.

1. How to apply red color for mouse overed cell? e.g.

Not mouse overed table:

```
000
000
000
```

Mouse over on cell at center(5)(it must be red, but still blue), with blue colored cells(1).

```
010
151
010
```

2. How to create smooth animation moving from old selected cell to new selected cell(e.g. in Excel 2013 you can see smooth animation of cell selector moving from cell to another cell)? I need the same effect. How to create them? See example:
   [image: Excelp 2013 cell navigation with smooth effect]

**UPDATE**
**1 question solved**
Second question solved by this ask: [how to animate element in table cell by cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848299/how-to-animate-element-in-table-cell-by-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/0ardb3u0/2/

You can get the cell with `$(this)`.
But i dont know about the smooth effect, because i dont have excel 2013.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hmm.. but el = $(this); , why the el.* var didn't work? but $(this).* work?

Comment: I added the gif, which explaing what I mean in smooth animation from selected cell to another cell. See how it smoothly moves from CC to GG.

Comment: you will have to make a div with red border as big as a cell and move it to the position of the active cell. if you give this div a transition value, you can make it move smoothly.

Comment: I need move blue cross selection with red too.

Comment: I fogot the important for CSS :(

Comment: @AlexLL: Please don't use !important for resaon. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0ardb3u0/4/) works fine without it. (since it was declared afterwards).