# How to transition a div between two parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have two containers:

```
<div class="left">
    <div id="myDiv">A Div</div>
    <div id="myDiv2">A Div</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div id="myDiv3">A Div</div>
</div>
```

The first contains `div` elements, which are moved with the following jQuery:

```
$(".left > div").click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('.right');
});
```

The above, however, provides no animation. I would like to use a CSS `transition` to animate each `div` between the two parent elements (From `.left` to `.right`).

By the way, this is my CSS:

```
.left, .right{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.left{background:red;}
.right{background:green; left: 50%;}
.left > div, .right > div{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

And a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x270Lndz/

---

I figure I need to get coordinates and transition between them, outside both `.left` and `.right`.

Comment: you want to transition the appending to a different parent? thats ... not how transitions work.

Comment: I figure I need to get coordinates and transition between them, outside the parents.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Right, they definitely wouldn't work naturally. It *might* be possible to predict the layout with a lot of javascript, but it would be difficult. Question for Mooseman: Do the containers have anything like a background color or a border, that would suddenly change in size when the elements are removed/added? That might suddenly make the challenge infinitely harder.

Comment: @Katana314 Nope! Each side is constant, and each `div` is exactly what you see: `100 x 100` blocks.

Comment: I know this code isn't a translate position but maybe some like this can give you a nice trans ... http://jsfiddle.net/x270Lndz/1/ ... Let me know if this works to post it as an answer

Comment: I think IMHO that this question doesn't fit SO because it imply a lot of coding, and honestly, I (and probably a lot of peoples) doesn't have the time for that... There is no simple solution to make it fluid. But using the coordinate is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Danko Thanks, but it really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok but as @Karl-AndréGagnon points the way you want it exactly will need a lot of code and involves more time, I don't see a little aproach on your question to get at least the coordinates of origin and final place, maybe try some and then make a puntual question

Comment: [I ended up writing a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27569643/1234256).

Comment: calculate coordinations, apply animation, and append in animation's callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.transitionTo = function(target){
    this.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        marginLeft = parseInt($this.css('marginLeft').replace("px", "")); 
        marginTop = parseInt($this.css('marginTop').replace("px", ""));
        offset = $this.offset();
        $new = $this.clone().appendTo(target);
        offsetNew = $new.css('opacity',0).offset();
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: offset.left - marginLeft,
            top: offset.top - marginTop
        }).appendTo("body");
        setTimeout(function(a,b){
            a.css({
                left: offsetNew.left - marginLeft,
                top: offsetNew.top - marginTop
            });
            setTimeout(function(a,b){
                b.replaceWith(a.removeAttr('style'));
            },2000,a,b); //Anim time
        },10,$this,$new);
    });
};
```

It is called similarly to `.appendTo`:

```
$(".left > div").click(function(){
    $(this).transitionTo('.right');
});
```

...and only requires `transition: top 2s ease, left 2s ease;` on the `div`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9yxrmvo/1/

---

The only known issue with this plugin is the lack of support for animating the original element's siblings.

Answer (score 5):

This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/974765/2725684

The problem is 2 parts, moving elements in the DOM, and animating that movement, but the suggested is:

1. Store the position of the div, in its resting state, in the first column.
2. Append the div to the second column, store that position.
3. Turn off the visibility of the div.
4. Create a clone of the div, positioned where the resting state one was at.
5. Animate this clone across to the position of the appended div.
6. Turn off the visibility of this clone.
7. Turn back on the original div that was appended.

The javascript/jquery will execute this so fast you won't see the turning off/on of the divs and it will just appear as if the div they are seeing is the only one that ever existed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `transition: 0.5s ease-in` to the `.left` div

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this is going to be a lot of work, and I don't think I have the time to write every step out in full. But, if you're committed, here goes:

1. Call `getBoundingClientRect()` or similar on the first element to get its absolute document position relative to the document / viewport.
2. Use the same function, and `getComputedStyle()`s padding to determine the exact pixel at which content would begin in the second div.
3. Determine the difference between the two coordinates, in order to fake the transition while the elements are still inside their first parent. (Or, move them first, and fake the transition after)
4. Apply the correct `transform: translate` style to the elements, so that they'll appear to move into the other container. (This is assuming you have the transition properties set up correctly in CSS)
5. On the `transitionend` event, turn off transitions, remove the transform property, and do the actual child move.
6. Pat yourself on the back and go home early.

So there you have it. There's likely going to be a lot of math involved and small additions/subtractions I'm not able to predict. Hopefully, that outline helps you get started at least. You might also be lucky enough to find an animation library that does all of this for you. (*Also note that I assumed the presence of several functions not supported on all browsers, so check to make sure they're okay by your book*)