# Dragging from d3 svg to html5

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I would like to be able to drag a d3 element out onto one of multiple html elements.

html

```
<div id="drop" class="drop-area" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  Drop it here like it's hot.
</div>
<div id="drop2" class="drop-area" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  Or, you know, drop it here (see if I care...).
</div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

js

```
drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on('dragstart', function(elem, ev) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  console.log(d3.event);
  // set some string on dataTransfer here
})

var w=960,h=500,
svg=d3.select("#chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width",w)
.attr("height",h);

var text=svg
.append("text")
.text("drag me")
.attr("y",50)
.call(drag);

drop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  console.log('dropped')
  // receive the string from dataTransfer here
}

allowDrop = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ec80L0hp/3/

So, in this example the `dragstart` event is fired but the drop areas don't recognize that anything is being dragged.

It looks like d3 is using `MouseEvent` instead of `DragEvent`?

I'm not super familiar with d3 so, maybe I'm going at that end of it wrong.

Note: I don't actually want the d3 element itself. I'll just want a string of data represented by the dragged d3 element. I want to extract that data in `dragstart` and attach it to `dataTransfer` (or I can store it somewhere else if I can get the html element to just register the drop without the `dataTransfer`...).

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876453/animate-dom-movement-of-svg-groupings/31878693#31878693 In your case #target it's not another svg rater a html container.

Comment: Thanks @Klaujesi, it looks like that answer moves elements `onclick`. In my case the drag and drop is important. It might not be obvious in my question. I'll update it with a bit more detail.

Comment: Hi. You can't pull off something from inside SVG container to HTML. You must simulate the effect. On star draging, create a clone and drag it. They are not treated as two different divs. Instead SVG has his own space.