# Animating an item moving from one list to another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two lists like so:

```
<ul id="list1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to click an item on list 1, have the unclicked items slide off screen to the left and then append the clicked item to the bottom of list 2. Instead of it just popping in existence though, I would like it slide from list 1 to list 2. The non-animated version looks like this in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list1 li").click(function() {
    chosenItem = this;
    $("#list1 li").each(function(index, element) {
      if (element != chosenItem) {
        $(element).hide();
      }
    });

    $(chosenItem).appendTo("#list2")

  })
});
```

I have tried animating a bunch of different ways, but it doesn't seem that list items are affected by anything I try that have to do with position. What is the best way to accomplish this type of animation?

http://jsfiddle.net/qvd3Lcf7/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could figure out an animation using transfrom: translateX() and translateY(), though I suspect it will be finicky and not all that attractive... Maybe something just as communicative and considerably simpler could be achieved using opacity fades? For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list1 li").click(function() {
    chosenItem = this;
    $("#list1 li").each(function(index, element) {
      if (element != chosenItem) {
        $(element).animate({opacity:0, marginLeft:"-=10px", marginRight: "+=10px"}, 500);
      }
    });

    $(chosenItem).animate({opacity:0}, 600, function() {
     $(chosenItem).appendTo("#list2").animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });

  })
});
```

```css
#list1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#list2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I just animate the unchosen elements to slide to the left as they fade out, while the chosen element fades out in the same position, then fades back in at its new location. If you must have a translation solution then I'm sure that's possible, but would probably require some work using absolute positioning. Look at the answers here:

[JQuery - animate moving DOM element to new parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907279/jquery-animate-moving-dom-element-to-new-parent)